# Why not magento provide all services in REST for android

Tags: php, android, magento

I just want to know whats the reason behind Magento not providing all services in rest. I know SOAP provide all but why not REST?

Comment: Despite REST being a far simpler standard, it is ironically a lot harder to implement, or rather, to "implement correctly".  As soon as you start detracting from the simplicity, you enter the world of RPC, and if at that point you "aren't" using a standard RPC protocol like SOAP, you are in serious trouble.

Comment: I think soap is much harder to implement compared to REST.

Comment: The technical barrier is harder yes.  But in REST, you aren't allowed to create an API that says `/check-state-and-run-tasks`.  Because that would be an "operation", and REST deals in the "transfer of resources", not operations.  Its hard to "design" I should have said.